# What is the status of NVIDIA SPIR support as of mid-2018?

Tags: opencl, nvidia, gpgpu, spir-v

This question:

[Does NVidia support OpenCL SPIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052832/does-nvidia-support-opencl-spir)

was asked 5 years ago. Since then, NVIDIA support for Khronos OpenCL has improved over this period, and it has also adopted Khronos Vulkan (of which I know little), I was wondering whether things had changed w.r.t. SPIR (the Khronos standards equivalent of PTX, if you will) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No change. NVIDIA does not support the `cl_khr_spir` extension ("SPIR 1.2") in their otherwise nice OpenCL 1.2 drivers (and SPIR-V is a 2.x thing, so also not supported).

Comment: But hasn't there been some experimental OpenCL 2.x support in recent NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: Yes, there have been 2.x additions. I almost wrote "OpenCL 1.2+ drivers" since that's what they call them, but I didn't want to confuse the topic. However, none of the 2.x additions include SPIR support at this time, that I know of.